# Error when run Hive-0.9.0 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: type

Tags: hive

Really sorry for stupid question, but struggling to find answer.  I am trying to start up Hive on my 3 node Hadoop cluster, HDFS runs OK as does PIG, Hbase but for the life of me I can not get Hive to run properly.

**This is the classpath output >**

```
:/home/hduser/hive-0.9.0/conf:/home/hduser/hive-0.9.0/lib/antlr-runtime-3.0.1.jar:/home/hduser/hive-0.9.0/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/home/hduser/hive-0.9.0/lib/commons-codec-1.3.jar:/home/hduser/hive-0.9.0/lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar:/home/hduser/hive-0.9.0/lib/commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:/home/hduser/hive-0.9.0/lib/commons-lang-2.4.jar:/home/hduser/hive-0.9.0/lib/commons-logging-1.0.4.jar:/home/hduser/hive-0.9.0/lib/commons-logging-api-1.0.4.jar:/home/hduser/hive-0.9.0/lib/commons-pool-1.5.4.jar:/home/hduser/hive-0.9.0/lib/datanucleus-connectionpool-2.0.3.jar:/home/hduser/hive-0.9.0/lib/datanucleus-core-2.0.3.jar:/home/hduser/hive-0.9.0/lib/datanucleus-enhancer-2.0.3.jar:/home/hduser/hive-0.9.0/lib/datanucleus-rdbms-2.0.3.jar:/home/hduser/hive-0.9.0/lib/derby-10.4.2.0.jar:/home/hduser/hive-0.9.0/lib/guava-r09.jar:/home/hduser/hive-0.9.0/lib/hadoop-0.20.2-core.jar:/home/hduser/hive-0.9.0/lib/hbase-0.92.0.jar:/home/hduser/hive-0.9.0/lib/hbase-0.92.0-tests.jar:/home/hduser/hive-0.9.0/lib/hive-builtins-0.9.0.jar:/home/hduser/hive-0.9.0/lib/hive-cli-0.9.0.jar:/home/hduser/hive-0.9.0/lib/hive-common-0.9.0.jar:/home/hduser/hive-0.9.0/lib/hive-contrib-0.9.0.jar:/home/hduser/hive-0.9.0/lib/hive_contrib.jar:/home/hduser/hive-0.9.0/lib/hive-exec-0.9.0.jar:/home/hduser/hive-0.9.0/lib/hive-hbase-handler-0.9.0.jar:/home/hduser/hive-0.9.0/lib/hive-hwi-0.9.0.jar:/home/hduser/hive-0.9.0/lib/hive-jdbc-0.9.0.jar:/home/hduser/hive-0.9.0/lib/hive-metastore-0.9.0.jar:/home/hduser/hive-0.9.0/lib/hive-pdk-0.9.0.jar:/home/hduser/hive-0.9.0/lib/hive-serde-0.9.0.jar:/home/hduser/hive-0.9.0/lib/hive-service-0.9.0.jar:/home/hduser/hive-0.9.0/lib/hive-shims-0.9.0.jar:/home/hduser/hive-0.9.0/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.8.8.jar:/home/hduser/hive-0.9.0/lib/jackson-jaxrs-1.8.8.jar:/home/hduser/hive-0.9.0/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.8.jar:/home/hduser/hive-0.9.0/lib/jackson-xc-1.8.8.jar:/home/hduser/hive-0.9.0/lib/JavaEWAH-0.3.2.jar:/home/hduser/hive-0.9.0/lib/jdo2-api-2.3-ec.jar:/home/hduser/hive-0.9.0/lib/jline-0.9.94.jar:/home/hduser/hive-0.9.0/lib/json-20090211.jar:/home/hduser/hive-0.9.0/lib/libfb303-0.7.0.jar:/home/hduser/hive-0.9.0/lib/libfb303.jar:/home/hduser/hive-0.9.0/lib/libthrift-0.7.0.jar:/home/hduser/hive-0.9.0/lib/libthrift.jar:/home/hduser/hive-0.9.0/lib/log4j-1.2.16.jar:/home/hduser/hive-0.9.0/lib/slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar:/home/hduser/hive-0.9.0/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar:/home/hduser/hive-0.9.0/lib/stringtemplate-3.1-b1.jar:/home/hduser/hive-0.9.0/lib/zookeeper-3.4.3.jar:
Logging initialized using configuration in file:/home/hduser/hive-0.9.0/conf/hive-log4j.properties
Hive history file=/tmp/hduser/hive_job_log_hduser_201212181716_326152902.txt
```

**and then from HIVE command line I run this:**

```
hive> CREATE TABLE pokes (foo INT, bar STRING);
```

**however I get the following error:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: type
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveLexer.mKW_CREATE(HiveLexer.java:1602)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveLexer.mTokens(HiveLexer.java:6380)
        at org.antlr.runtime.Lexer.nextToken(Lexer.java:89)
        at org.antlr.runtime.BufferedTokenStream.fetch(BufferedTokenStream.java:133)
        at org.antlr.runtime.BufferedTokenStream.sync(BufferedTokenStream.java:127)
        at org.antlr.runtime.CommonTokenStream.setup(CommonTokenStream.java:132)
        at org.antlr.runtime.CommonTokenStream.LT(CommonTokenStream.java:91)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.statement(HiveParser.java:547)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseDriver.parse(ParseDriver.java:438)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:416)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:336)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:909)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:258)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:215)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:406)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:689)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:557)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:156)
```

Comment: Can you please attach the entire exception trace?

Comment: Hmmmm ok really stupid question, I thought I would see log files in hive.log.dir=/tmp/${user.name} however when I check I see hive.log which is empty and a file of todays date i.e. hive_job_log_hduser_201212241042_1581108083.txt which only contains:  SessionStart SESSION_ID="hduser_201212241042" TIME="1356345729842".   I have changed log4j config from WARN to ALL. (Apologies and thanks for any help)

Comment: You are most likely looking at the wrong location for logs. Perhaps, you should be looking somewhere under /var

Comment: make sure you have same hive-exec*.jar under hive/lib on server and /user/oozie/share/lib/hive/hive-exec*.jar

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't have any other antlr-*.jar in your classpath except the one which is there in HIVE_HOME/lib folder. If still doesn't work download the latest version from the antlr's website and put it into the HIVE_HOME/lib folder and give it a try.
HTH

Comment: Thanks very much for the advice, I checked echo $PATH and no reference to antlr. Then added echo $HADOOP_CLASSPATH to the ./hive script which I can see picks up any jars which are in my HIVE_HOME/lib folder.  I tried replacing with latest antlr jar but still no joy.

Answer (score 0):

just remove all the files with prefix jackson*
and copy new version of jackson* files from hive.

rm /opt/hadoop/hadoop/lib/jackson*
cp /opt/hive/hive/lib/jackson* /opt/hadoop/hadoop/lib

I did it this way, and it worked perfectly fine!

I hope it helps.